# Izpack under Maven using wrong 'installFile'

Tags: maven, maven-3, izpack

I am using Maven to build an installer using IzPack. As far as I can see (relevant part of POM included below), I am asking for the install file to be ${basedir}/izpack/release.xml.

In practice (when using -e on maven) I get the following debug:

- [DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.izpack:izpack-maven-plugin:5.0.0-beta10:izpack' with basic configurator
- [DEBUG]   (f) baseDir = C:\Users\Phil\git\v2\Install\target/staging
- [DEBUG]   (f) comprFormat = default
- [DEBUG]   (f) comprLevel = -1
- [DEBUG]   (f) installFile = C:\Users\Phil\git\v2\Install/src/main/izpack/install.xml
- [DEBUG]   (f) kind = release
- [DEBUG]   (f) output = C:\Users\Phil\git\v2\Install\target/install-2.4.5-SNAPSHOT-installer.jar
      [DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.erudine:install:2.4.5-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\Phil\git\v2\Install\pom.xml

The important point is that the install file is is ../src/main. I don't actually have a src/main in this project, so it looks like I am picking up a default by mistake.

The page http://izpack.codehaus.org/izpack-maven-plugin/izpack-mojo.html, describes the properties, and as far as I can see descriptor is the correct one to use. I get 'unrecognised tag' if I move descriptor outside the configuration block, so I suspect that it is in the correct place but being ignored.

I have moved the release.xml to the file locations specified by the [debug] and to my surprise the installer did it's thing, so I think the rest of the configuration is specificed correctly. I do however have multiple separate installers I want to create, and I would like to be able to control the descriptor.

Software stack

- Windows 7
- Jdk1.6.0_29-b11
- Maven 3.0.3
- Izpack 5.0.0-beta10

Maven POM
        
            org.codehaus.izpack
            izpack-maven-plugin
            5.0.0-beta10

```
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>build-izpack-release-installer</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>izpack</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptor>${basedir}/izpack/release.xml</descriptor>
                    <izpackBasedir>${staging.dir}</izpackBasedir>
                    <kind>release</kind>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>

    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK after some investigation I have come to the conclusion that (surprise) the documentation is wrong. The correct tag to use is <installFile>